# Slack slash command: set bot name and icon

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, slack-api

I'm trying to make a node slack bot. When I hit the route from Slack,

`app.get('/testbot', testbot);`

I call testbot:

**testbot.js:**

```
postToSlack(botPayload, function (error, status, body) {
     console.log('successfully posted to slack');
});
```

I'm posting my payload object to the Webhook URL specified in their [Slack API](https://fuzzpro.slack.com/services/8278638087?added=1): "https://hooks.slack.com/services/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"

```
function postToSlack (payload, callback) {
    var val = JSON.stringify(payload);
    request({
        uri: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/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&payload=val',
        method: 'POST'
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            return callback(error);
        }
        console.log('RESPONSE', body); //takes forever, then eventually comes back as { }
        callback(null, response.statusCode, body);
    });
}
```

`console.log('RESPONSE', body)` doesn't return anything.

My test botPayload object looks like:

```
var botPayload = {};
botPayload.text = 'This should be working';
botPayload.username = 'my_new_bot';
botPayload.channel = '#mychannel';
botPayload.icon_url = 'http://i.imgur.com/IciaiJt.png';
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

How can I remove the BOT label from the post?

[image]

Comment: The 'uri' being sent to the request method contains '...&payload=val'. Did you intend for that to be '...&payload=' + val; ?  Also, the value of val is raw json, I think you might want to encodeURIComponent that.

Comment: ... or alternatively, if this is the request module, remove &payload=val from the uri , and send a new parameter to the request module of form: {payload: val}.

Comment: @mmccaff Hi I was able to resolve that. I've added a new issue above. How do I remove "BOT" from the name?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. Any web-hook integration that I've done shows 'bot' and I assumed that Slack does that as a security measure to make real users distinguishable from bots. I haven't seen an option to remove that. The screenshots in their docs do not show 'bot', so either the docs are outdated or there is a way... I'd ask them.